# How can I change the login page background to dark?

Tags: login, mate-desktop, theme, appearance, parrotsec

So I'm using Parrot Security OS (Mate based UI), and I accidentally change the theme, but while I switch it back, the login page's background (the small box where you chose user and enter password) change from dark to light. I've thought that the default theme might be a customized theme so I enter live mode in the installer and grab the default theme, but while I later paste it to `~/.theme` the login page background doesn't changes back. How can I fix it?

#### Edit:

I've try to install ParrotSec on other drive and this time the login box background color change on next reboot, and I didn't even touch the appearence part. Why?

Comment: The login screen is unlikely to read files from your home directory since it does not know what user is going to log in. What graphical login manager is in use? GDM?

Comment: @Kusalananda How can I know which manager it's using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe install lightdm-settings and change the theme:

[image]